# Does "I seen that" really mean "I've seen that"?

Tags: ellipses

"I seen it."
"I got it."

The two I can think of that are often (incorrectly) said. I guess "I got it" could be used to express that you got the new car you were looking at, but to me, "I seen it" is just "I've seen it" without the 've.

Comment: Try pronouncing a word starting with /zg, vg,/ or /vs/. If you're a native English speaker, you'll have difficulty with those clusters, yet that's what they're sposta contract to: /ay vsinət, ay vgatət/.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, I think it does. Either "I've seen that" or "I saw that".

Comment: Would the -1 care to explain?

Comment: Your answer provides no explanation.